# UIStatusBarStyle lightContent not being honored on Modally Presented View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uistatusbar

I am attempting to change the text color of the status bar from black to white on a Modally Presented View Controller embedded in a Navigation Controller called *ChildViewController*

I am using the [Chameleon framework](https://github.com/viccalexander/Chameleon) for colors.

I can change the background color with no issues using:

```
guard let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else {fatalError("Navigation controller does not exist.")}
guard let navBarColour = UIColor(hexString: colourHexCode) else { fatalError()}

navBar.barTintColor = navBarColour
navBar.tintColor = ContrastColorOf(navBarColour, returnFlat: true)
navBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : ContrastColorOf(navBarColour, returnFlat: true)]
```

I have tried multiple combination of the below in `viewWillAppear` & `viewDidLoad` in *ChildViewController*

```
self.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true

UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

setStatusBarStyle(.lightContent)


override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

I have even tried Chameleons own  `self.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyleContrast)` but again nothing is working.

In my `Info.plist` I have:

`View controller-based status bar appearance = YES`

And in the General Project settings under *Deployment Info* the Status Bar Style is set to `Default`

Targeting iOS 11.4 with Swift 4.1

**What am I doing wrong?**